# Matplotlib plotting date from datetime instead of time

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, raspberry-pi

Output from converted CSV datetime (HH:MM:SS) being plotted as date on x axis, I've been trying to plot as time but haven't been able to manage it.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

headers = ['Time','Sensor Value']
df = pd.read_csv('/home/pi/Desktop/CSVLogfile.csv',usecols=[1,2],names=headers)
print (df)

df['Time'] = df['Time'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), '%H:%M:%S'))
df['Time'].map(lambda x: datetime.strftime(x, '%H:%M:%S'))

x = df['Time']
y = df['Sensor Value']

# plot
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

Comment: you have imported datetime, and used that to define time , right ?

Comment: I think so, with datetime.strptime. It's just matplotlib reading the time column as dates for some reason?

Comment: You cannot plot times without dates. But of course you are free to just use any date you want if only interested in time.

Comment: Thanks but how can I plot time?

Comment: As said, you cannot plot time alone. It will always have a date (maybe today's date, or the first of january of the year 0001).

Answer (score 0):

Just define a random date and then use a formatter to only include the time component of your information.

You should be able to include a random date and combine the 2 strings. Something like this should work:

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime('20180101-'+str(x), '%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S'))
```

Then set your plotting format using something like this so that your added date is not shown:

```
plt.rcParams["date.autoformatter.minute"] = "%H:%M:%S"
```